# req.body is [Object : null prototype]{} while using multer

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, multer, busboy

i want to upload an image in nodejs with multer  but i have some issues

in my server.js (main) i have

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const expressBusboy = require('express-busboy');
expressBusboy.extend(app,{upload : true , path : 'uploads/'});
```

and in routes/index.js i have

```
const multer = require('multer')
const upload = multer()
router.post('/products',upload.single('photo'),handeler)
router.post('/test',handeler)
```

the handeler func just logs somethings in console now i have 3 problems
1: when i send a request to /test which does not include upload.single the req.body object is define and its ok but when i send the same request to /products which includes upload.single('some name') req.files is define and ok but req.body is [Object : null prototype]{}
why this is happening?
2: why while iam using upload.single() i have req.files instead of req.file and req.files is an object with just one object in it
3: when i receive the request the file that i want to be uploaded will store in a new folder named as its uuid instead of directly saving in the uploads folder that i already created , i tried to add allowedPath : /^/upload$/  (i copied this regex maybe its wrong for here)but it stopped storing 
and iam using postman to sending request and iam using form-data for body and the texts have been added before file i checked and in headers of request content type has been set to multipart/form-data

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem
it happened because I was using both busboy and multer together
I started sending form-data(s) without uploading files and I needed busboy to parse requests body and after that I installed multer to upload my images and that made them overwrite each other and problems appeared